# How to declare similar structure with different number of fields?

Tags: c, structure, redefinition

I have 2 headers that need to define 2 similar structures. One structure should be aligned to 32bytes and other is similar but doesn't need to align to 32bytes so I can save some memory here. One is included in the other. Here is main_header.h

```
struct mainStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    char pad[20];
};
```

Following is sub_header.h

```
#include "main_header.h"

struct subStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Now what I wish to do is define `subStruct` in a way that, whenever i change `mainStruct` other than `pad[20]` all other fields should be updated in `subStruct`. That is, if tomorrow, I make `mainStruct` like this:

```
struct mainStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    char pad[16];
};
```

then, automatically it should be reflected in `sub_header.h` as

```
struct subStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};
```

Is there an efficient way of doing it using some kind of Macros or other preprocessor directives??

And subStruct should always be derived from mainStruct and not other way around, this is very important.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cant you define mainStruct as a member of subStruct like struct subStruct{ struct mainStruct * mMainObj;}; ?

Comment: Is there a possiblilty of using `C++` here because `C++` has just what you need `Inheritance`.

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider the other way around; including `subStruct` as an element in `mainStruct`? Like this:

```
struct sub {
    int a, b, c;
};
struct main {
    struct sub head;
    char dummy[16];
};
```

True, it does take an extra layer of syntax to get at `a`, `b` or `c`, but the memory layout and performance should be the same.

Otherwise, there's nothing preventing you from using a macro, as you suggest yourself:

```
#define SUB_FIELDS int a; int b; int c;

struct main {
    SUB_FIELDS
    char dummy[16];
};
struct sub {
    SUB_FIELDS
};
```

Comment: Well, likely this is the simplest solution, however big hierarchies looks ugly in this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's why C++ was initially invented. But if you wish to stay with plain C (there could be reasons for such decision) you may check GLib / GObject type system implemented as a set of macros over plain C.